# Including a stand-alone copy of a Database inside Published VS2010 C# Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have designed a small C# Windows Forms project in VS2010 & now want to Publish it and test it on another PC. I seem to recall seeing an option when I was first setting the Database up, that if I set that option on, a complete stand-alone copy of the SQL Server database would be included in the published project, so that even a PC without SQL Server of any kind installed, would be able to run the program ... but I can't remember where I saw it or, obviously now, how to choose that option !!!

Can somebody please tell me where I saw this and how to set this option on ?

UPDATE ...

OK, I think I've found out what to do here, as when I installed it onto the other PC it automatically downloaded and installed SQL Server 2008, I changed options in the Solution Explorer Properties / Publish / Prerequisites ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have simple needs for a local DB you could use SQLServer Compact Edition.  SQL CE runs in process within your app.